# SVN checkout without restoring

Tags: svn, conflict, resolve, svn-checkout

We have some company middleware and sometimes its difficult to find the correct version Im looking for so I often have to update to different versions to test them.

I usually checkout:

```
svn co svn+ssh://(username)@(ip)/srv/svn/intranet/trunk/PYTHON/<application> <local-application>
```

I then may update to a different version

```
svn update (path) -r (rev)
```

Most of the time after a few attempts this will cause the error **Node remains in conflict**

If I delete the folder and try to do a fresh checkout it just restores what I had. All I want to do is checkout a revision, I have made no changes and it still thinks there are conflicts.

Ive tried to resolve them, but nothing seems to work:

svn update  -r 1586

```
Skipped 'inm/inm' -- Node remains in conflict
D    inm/fabfile.py
D    inm/test.db.bak
D    inm/tests
D    inm/test.db
D    inm/doc
D    inm/test.ini
D    inm/test.sql
U    inm/setup.py
A    inm/inm.egg-info
A    inm/inm.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
A    inm/inm.egg-info/top_level.txt
A    inm/inm.egg-info/PKG-INFO
A    inm/inm.egg-info/entry_points.txt
A    inm/inm.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
A    inm/inm.egg-info/not-zip-safe
A    inm/inm.egg-info/paster_plugins.txt
A    inm/inm.egg-info/requires.txt
U    inm/setup.cfg
Updated to revision 1586.
Killed by signal 15.
Summary of conflicts:
  Skipped paths: 1

svn resolved inm/inm
Resolved conflicted state of 'inm/inm'
(venv)

svn update inm/inm -r 1586
Updating 'inm/inm':
Password: 
Skipped 'inm/inm/templates' -- Node remains in conflict
At revision 1586.
Killed by signal 15.
Summary of conflicts:
  Skipped paths: 1
```

Comment: maybe untracked files cause the conflict; it's not very clear, what state/contents of that directory("path", is it the same as "intranet/trunk/PYTHON/<application>"?) you had before and after each operation; and what's your SVN version?

Comment: If you think this is definitely a bug, write to users@subversion.apache.org or #svn channel at FreeNode

Comment: if you haven't update anything in the working copy, normally it won't behave like that.  Just to make sure, are you updating the whole working copy to different rev, or just part of it?  If it is the former case, it seems to me that's a bug in svn instead.

Comment: Im using subversion-1.7.5-1.fc17.i686. It is the exact same path, Im literally just trying to get a new revision. Whatever I do it will not seem to just download the latest copy. Im trying to update the whole working copy.

Comment: Also, when I try to delete the whole file and then update again, it just misses entire sections out (the ones that are in conflict) and doesnt error at all

Comment: The second time it complains about another conflicting node. Maybe you should resolve the conflict with '--depth=infinity' option and something '--accept theirs' in order not to resolve every file manually. But anyway, strange.. Could you post the output of "svn status inm" before and after update?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think the answer I was looking for here was

```
svn revert --depth=infinity inm
```

I dont care about keeping local changes, only to update to a new revision. I have used this command a few times now and it seems to do the trick

**EDIT**

Upon looking at my errors again I can see that a lot of the files were likely being changed by tests or builds. I should have added them to an ignore file so that their changes were not detected by svn.

Answer (score 1):

So:

- Are you only checking out and updating from `trunk`, or are you sometimes checking out from a branch too?
- Do you run any programs while testing?
- What if you did a `svn status` before you ran the update? Do you have a pristine copy of a checkout?

Conflicts can happen for many reasons.

Imagine you've modified a file that's in your Subversion repository and then did an update to an earlier version or later version. Depending how you do it, Subversion may try to merge the changes between what you did and what you are checking out. Sometimes, Subversion won't if you're not updating from the head of a revision. In that case, Subversion will report that the file is in conflict.

Another reason is that you created a file in your working directory that is not in your revision of Subversion. When you do an update to a revision of Subversion with that file, Subversion will report a conflict.

Then, maybe there's just something wrong with your system. We simply don't have enough information right now.

The next time you do this, do a `svn status` on your working directory before you do an `svn update`. In fact, that's always a good idea. This will warn you of any possible conflict with Subversion when you do an update.

One of the things I miss in Subversion that CVS had (and I don't miss much about CVS) was an option that pretends to execute your command. This would allow you to pretend to do an update and warn you of conflicts before you did an actual update. Alas, Subversion doesn't currently have such an option (although it has been heavily requested).